# Getting text from labels inside gridview cells (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

### VB

I've got a gridview in which I need to use template columns, therefore instead of being able to retrieve text straight from the cell, it's inside of a label. All the labels have different ids as well so I would like to programmatically retrieve the label inside a cell then look at the text inside the label.

This is what I have got at the moment, however it never manages to return the text and instead returns the empty string ("").

```
Public Function ReturnLabelText(ByVal c As TableCell) As String
    For Each lb In c.Controls
        If lb.[GetType]() = GetType(Label) Then
            Return CType(lb, Label).Text()
        End If
    Next
    Return ""
End Function
```

The function is called on this line:

```
doc.ReplaceText("@" + gridView.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Text.ToLower, ReturnLabelText(row.Cells(i)).Replace("&nbsp;", "").Replace(vbCr, ""))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `GridViewRow.FindControl("ControlID")` to get the reference of the `Label`.

So for example, if you want to loop loop all rows:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In Me.GridView1.Rows
    Dim label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("LabelID"), Label)
    Dim text As String = label.Text
    ' ... '
Next
```

But if you want to set it's text on databinding i'd use the `GridView.RowDataBound` event instead:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    Select Case e.Row.RowType
        Case DataControlRowType.DataRow
             Dim label = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("LabelID"), Label)
             Dim text As String = label.Text
    ' ... '
    End Select
End Sub
```

You can even get the `DataSource` of each row via `e.Row.DataItem` to access all fields.

---

If you have a `TableCell` and you want to get all labels in it you could also use `OfType`:

```
Dim firstLabel = c.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().FirstOrDefault()
If firstLabel  IsNot Nothing Then Return firstLabel.Text
Return Nothing
```

Comment: But I don't want to have to specify the LabelID. Instead I just want to get all controls from the cell and return the label's text.

Comment: I only need to read the text as I loop through every cell of every row.

Comment: @JacobMason: have a look at my edited answer. You can use `OfType` to filter and cast to Label. However, why can't you use `FincControl("ID")`? That makes your code more robust and readable.

Comment: I thought that if you use FindControl("ID") you have to specify the label's name and if I am looping through 5 different columns, then each label is going to have a different ID i.e "Label1", "Label2", etc?

Comment: @JacobMason: yes, but if you'd use more meaningful names than `Label1`, `Label123` it would increase readability. For example: `Dim lblName = DirectCast(row.FindControl("LblName"), Label) Dim name = lblName.Text`. It also prevents careless mistakes.

Comment: I tried your ofType suggestion, however I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Comment: @JacobMason: where did you get it? Have you seen that i've used `If firstLabel  IsNot Nothing`? But if i remember correctly, if you use a `TemplateField` the first and only control in the `TableCell` is a `LiteralControl` which is the container. Then you need to use `c.Controls(0).Controls.OfType(Of Label)().FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @TimSchemelter doc.ReplaceText("@" + gridView.HeaderRow.Cells(i).Text.ToLower, row.Cells(i).Controls.OfType(Of Label)().FirstOrDefault.Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "").Replace(vbCr, "")) That's how I used it.

Comment: @JacobMason: note that i've edited my last comment. But you see that this is horrible code ;)

Comment: @TimSchemelter I used the OfType(OfLabel)().FirstOrDefault.Text to get the text but it couldn't find a label, even though there is one. Is that really horrible code?

Comment: @JacobMason: have you noticed that i've edited my last comment as mentioned to provide the code which should work? I've called that code horrible since it's error-prone. Consider that you change the content in future and you add other controls to this columns. It will fail on runtime or -  even worse - returns the text of the wrong label.

Comment: @TimSchemelter I am using your code but replaced c. with the a different reference to the cell. row.Cells(i).Controls.OfType(Of Label)().FirstOrDefault.Text  It still refuses to work however.

Comment: @JacobMason: because you still haven't read my comment. You have to search in the `Controls` of the first control in the cell which is a `Literal` control: `row.Cells(i).Controls(0).Controls.OfType(Of Label)().FirstOrDefault.Text`. That's what i'm calling ugly code ^^ It's relying on an implementation detail of ASP.NET which might change in future. Use `row.FindControl` to find the correct control.

Comment: @TimeSchemelter I did read it, I just misunderstood haha. I have now changed it to your suggestion of row.Cells(i).Controls(0).Controls.OfType(Of Label)().FirstOrDefault with no luck, the reference is still null.

Comment: @JacobMason: try: `e.Row.Cells(i).Controls(1)`, it seems that the label is the second control and not a child control, the first is really a `Literal` control. So this should also work:  `e.Row.Cells(i).Controls.OfType(Of Label)().First()`

Comment: @TimSchemelter Using that new code you suggested, I am now getting Sequence contains no elements

Comment: @JacobMason: maybe because that column has no label. Sorry, i'm out of office now. Good luck.

Comment: Still no luck here. I've stepped through the code and found what's contained. 0-Literal 1-WebControl.Label 2-Literal. From this it would seem the control at index 1 is the right one, which it is! But when I go to cast it to a Label it errors.

Comment: Dim firstLabel = c.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().FirstOrDefault() is a perfect answer, exactly what i'm looking for